# How to remove shadow in actionbar setted using FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE

Tags: android, android-layout

In an old android project I have a custom actionbar setted using FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.navbar_main);
```

It's working fine but I have to delete the shadow created by the bar and the bottom border

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`

Comment: The app doesn't use SupportActionBar

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this way to drop shadow for my toolbars. In XML file, Toolbar section:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/indian_red"
        android:elevation="10dp">
```

You should try to set ELEVATION to ( 0 )